# South African boy grows up in indecision, and stands aside while shaman obliterates the Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A boy grows up in rural South Africa, raised partly by his white family and partly by the local black people. He is particularly impressed by the tribal shaman. As he grows up and travels, he has many life experiences that are characterized by indecision about moral and ethical issues, particularly race-related issues. When he returns to South Africa, the shaman is still there and still wise. The shaman offers the young man a chance to fulfill himself; they take a drug and their spirit selves become enlarged, so large that they are of astronomical size, looking down on the tiny Earth. The shaman, who has no doubt in him whatever, turns to his protege and says that is now time to act. When the young man, again, fails to make a forthright decision, the shaman turns back to the Earth and spits on it. The Earth crackles briefly and is gone, obliterated, whereupon the spirit shaman enlarges rapidly to become one with the universe. But the young man's spirit is left to drift through space, his scream engulfing the stars.

The story was one of the first that I read in a new science fiction magazine, fresh off a news stand, in English, probably in the late 1960s. I would not be surprised if I have some of the details out of place, but the end of the story is distinctive.

Comment: What magazines were you reading? What country were you in?

Comment: I was in the United States. I rarely bought magazines at that time, but I remember Analog and the Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction. The magazine was printed on pulp, not glossy paper, in a small (less than the typical letter size) format.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum I have gone through the checklists, but the only extra detail I've come up with is that the magazine was new when I read it, presumably in the late 1960s. It was off a news stand, so it must have been one of the more common magazines of the day. I often rely on cover art in the ISFDB to help identify books I've read, but have gone through their images of Galaxy, Analog, and the Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction without finding a cover I recognize for this story. In fifty years I could have forgotten, though I usually have a good memory for formerly owned items.

Comment: Sorry for correcting the title the wrong direction. I misunderstood.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron - I suspect you can come up with more.  How old was the "boy"? How old was the "Shaman". Were there any adult themes (sex, violence)? Do you remember anything the characters said? Do you remember the character's names? How did he travel to SA in the first place? What did his family do that took them to SA? Why did he leave? Why did he return?

Comment: OK. I did have a copy of Analog, Sep. 1966. Overlooked that in my search because the cover was already familiar, so that may be it. Scanning through the contents on ISFDB, I don't recall what Hal Clement's "The Mechanic", Carole E. Scott's "A Matter of Reality", and Joseph P. Martino's "...Not a Prison Make" were about, and haven't found more information on the Web, so they are possible matches. 

Before I post these questions, I generally think about them overnight and often come up with more details the next morning. Some of them have been questions running for several years.

Comment: The boy was born in South Africa and left for his (college? college prep?) education elsewhere. He spent most of his life away from his home, and had diverse experiences. The tone of the story was one of him feeling lost and disappointed in himself. He returned to resolve this. The shaman lived apart from the others in a cave overlooking the area. I think there were two illustrations, one showing the aged shaman just outside the cave on the steep slope, smoke rising, at the beginning, and the other showing the end with the cosmic scream. But here I may be fantasizing.

Comment: Wait, the magazine had interior illustrations? You're sure about that? I think that pretty much rules out *F&SF*. Before you said that, I was thinking it sounded more line an *F&SF* story than an *Analog* story. Were you reading any *Galaxy*, *If*, *Amazing*, *Fantastic*?

Comment: @user14111, I read very few magazines. Going through the tables of contents in the ISFDB, I have been struck by how much I missed. Oh well. Using your suggestion, I have recognized one other cover that I owned, so this may be the source: _Fantastic,_ June 1964 (http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58219). The story is evidently not Binder, "From the Beginning," or Ellison, "Paingod", which are described online. But I haven't found information on the others.

Comment: This one? https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_v13n06_1964-06. Nope, not there.

Comment: @user14111 Wow. Didn't know that was in the Internet Archive. But you're right, the story is not in this issue.

Comment: @user14111 I have checked covers on the ISFDB for _Amazing, Fantastic, Galaxy, If, Magazine of Science Fiction and Fantasy,_ and identified just one more issue that I know I owned as a kid: _Fantastic,_ September 1966. I found one of the stories online ("No More Tomorrows" by David H. Keller): not it, but I remembered the story and its illustration once I saw it. The issue is of some note for containing Doris Pischeria's first published story ("Rocket to Gehenna") and one of the first uses of the word _psionic_, in Murray Leinster's "The Psionic Mousetrap".

Comment: I would have been 13 when I first saw this issue, and I probably discarded all three magazines the next year, when we moved. They were among the first SF I ever read.

Comment: @user14111 So close and yet so far! As it turns out, the magazine where I read the story, _Great Science Fiction_ No. 4 (1966), reused the cover art from _Fantastic_, (June 1964), which I noted as recognized in the comments above. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has descriptions matching ["The Funnel of God" by Robert Bloch.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62420) (1960)

It is about  a man who meets, first in childhood, then much later as an adult, an ancient native Zulu shaman living in the mountains above his Dutch/English kraal in South Africa in times of apartheid.

> When Harvey Wolf was seven, he met the Black Skelm.

His “folks” tell him that the shaman eats children, and order him to stay away.

He disobeys, has an encounter, finds otherwise. The old man is bizarre, and lives among bats and vultures, and drinks cattle blood from a skull. The old man tells Harvey he must grow up, leave, and find his own path.

Although it has been years since I have read it, here is a summary of a goodly part of the story.
Harvey grows up, moves to Europe and America, becomes a seeker, becomes a millionaire, studies with brilliant doctors, learns and discusses with them how science and mystical experience and “miraculous” healing might intersect.

There is good social commentary in each of his endeavors. He learns of consumerism, racial prejudice, the problems of the asphalt jungle and its billboards, gender stereotypes and phoniness.

> He deplored the phony virility of men’s magazines, the fake coyness of women’s magazines, and the artificial social values which emotionally warped young people into “manliness” or “femininity”.
>
> He held opinions which would automatically antagonize all fraternity members, morticians, professional evangelists, Texans, and the marchers in St. Patrick’s Day parades.

This is a short summary of an involved story. For anything longer, go read it yerself!

Much, much later he returns to his old kraal, mourns the people who left or died, and finds the Black Skelm, who said that he psychically saw Harvey coming back to him.

The Black Skelm offers Harvey a dark, shriveled object, suggests they take it together, and says that the hard shell is "our human consciousness”, and that when that is broken their true psyche shall be liberated to roam the universe.

So far he speaks like the kind of shaman almost anyone would yearn to meet.

> “Every man is God, or contains within him the seeds of godhead. Look.”
> The Black Skelm fumbled with a little leather pouch at his waist and drew forth a dark, shriveled object.
>
> Shall we open the shell and partake?”

To summarize a long, descriptive part of this story, they partake together, and behold the universe as if they could hold a sun in one hand.

Something goes sour, and though the Black Skelm says that he is above hate, he calls the earth "a speck, a mite, an errant, inconsequential atom".

> But the black, brooding face stared down and pursed its lips. Suddenly, it blew, and spat. A cloud of ichor issued from the titanic, toothless maw. It spiraled, gathering speed and form as it fell, twisting into a tunneling black cloud.  . . . .
>
> The cloud encompassed the earth.  . . . .
>
> Then the spittle evaporated into nothingness and and what it had encompassed was gone.
> Gone? It had never existed.
>
> Harvey's mouth opened, swallowing the universe in a soundless scream. He could not follow the Black Skelm, grow into godhead. He could not go back to an earth which no longer existed, had never existed.

So apparently power does corrupt, and absolute power corrupts absolutely.

It took me a long time to rediscover this story after so many years.

I agree with a SF anthology editor's statement about one of Bloch's stories: "This will stick like a burr in your memory."

....

Dang. I read it in "The Best of Robert Bloch" a few decades ago, but it was in Fantastic and it did have one illustration. And, like another Robert Bloch story I sought for years before finding, it made it on the cover.

[The Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantastic_v09n01_1960-01_LennyS-cape1736/mode/1up?view=theater)

and

[image: The Cover]

Comment: That's it. I read it in [_Great Science Fiction_ No. 4](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?253462) (1966). With illustrations. And yes, it stuck like a burr in my memory. Thank you.